# Trying to connect PostrgreSQL with my server to create SQL auth. for SOGo

Tags: sql-server, authentication, postgresql, ubuntu-14.04

I need to create SQL authentification for my SOGo installation, and I believe I have set up everything accoring to the documentation. They want me to do the following:

1st they want me to create database user `sogo` and schema of the db (here is the section: https://sogo.nu/files/docs/SOGoInstallationGuide.html#_database_configuration) with these commands:

```
su - postgres
createuser --no-superuser --no-createdb --no-createrole \
    --encrypted --pwprompt sogo
(specify “sogo” as password)
createdb -O sogo sogo
```

Then add the following line to postgresql `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
host   sogo   sogo     127.0.0.1/32     md5
```

And finaly modify the following lines in sogo.conf:

```
SOGoProfileURL =
    "postgresql://sogo:sogo@localhost:5432/sogo/sogo_user_profile";
OCSFolderInfoURL =
    "postgresql://sogo:sogo@localhost:5432/sogo/sogo_folder_info";
OCSSessionsFolderURL =
    "postgresql://sogo:sogo@localhost:5432/sogo/sogo_sessions_folder";
```

Then for the actuall authentification, I need to adjust the SOGoUserSources followingly:

```
SOGoUserSources =
(
  {
    type = sql;
    id = directory;
    viewURL = "postgresql://sogo:sogo@127.0.0.1:5432/sogo/sogo_view";
    canAuthenticate = YES;
    isAddressBook = YES;
    userPasswordAlgorithm = md5;
  }
);
```

which I also did, but unfortunatelly, I am not sure how to then create the database and table of users, to work with this auth. process.

I created a sogo database with sogo being also the owner, here is my list of databases:

```
 Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
--------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 sogo         | sogo     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 sogocreatedb | sogo     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 template0    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
              |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
              |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

Then I created a `sogo_view` table, as I thought that thats what I am supposed to do. Here is a list of relations:

```
List of relations
 Schema |   Name    | Type  | Owner
--------+-----------+-------+-------
 public | sogo_view | table | sogo
```

Finaly, I created a user in the table:

```
 c_uid  | c_name  |  c_password   |  c_cn   |          mail
---------+---------+---------------+---------+-------------------------
 Luciano | Luciano | Something    | Luciano | luciano@something.cz
```

But the connection is still not happening, does anyone have any experience with this ?

Answer (score 4):

In your password column you should set the MD5 of your password. Insert a record like this:

```
INSERT INTO sogo_view VALUES (
  'Luciano', 'Luciano', MD5('Something'),
  'Luciano', 'luciano@something.cz');
```

In the debian wiki there's an instruction of how to setup the db and insert logins. It's for mysql, but works for postgres as well. Just make sure you set the db and table owner to `sogo`, which you apparently did anyway.

In the debian example the user table is called `sogo_users` instead of `sogo_view`. So either rename it to `sogo_view` in the example below or change your SOGo config `viewURL` to `.../sogo_users`. Here's the original debian example:

```
CREATE TABLE sogo_users (
    c_uid VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    c_name VARCHAR(10),
    c_password VARCHAR(32),
    c_cn VARCHAR(128),
    mail VARCHAR(128));

INSERT INTO sogo_users VALUES ('paul', 'paul', MD5('zxc'), 'Paul Example', 'paul@example.com');
INSERT INTO sogo_users VALUES ('piet', 'piet', MD5('zxc'), 'Piet Jansen', 'piet@example.com');
INSERT INTO sogo_users VALUES ('klaas', 'klaas', MD5('zxc'), 'Klaas van der Zee', 'klaas@example.com');
```

Reference: https://wiki.debian.org/SOGo

Answer (score -1):

What is the exact error message being thrown by the program when it attempts to connect?

I note that you have

`sogocreatedb | sogo     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |`

in your list of databases. Did you intend to create a `sogocreatedb` database?

Comment: Please ask for clarifications in the comments and not in answers.